# gcloud kubernetes node pool: high priority for preemptible VM nodes possible

Tags: kubernetes, nodes, gcloud, pool

i need a solution for that:

i have 2 node pools in gcloud kubernetes, first is preemptible and autoscaling, second is only autoscaling.

Jobs should be started on the first one ( with preemptible VMs ), but when no resources on the first pool are available Jobs should be started on the second one.

How can i realize that, maybe with Taints and Tolerations?

Comment: Im also facing same problem. At the moment, `Estafette GKE Node Pool Shifter` could be temporary solution? https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/containers-kubernetes/cutting-costs-with-google-kubernetes-engine-using-the-cluster-autoscaler-and-preemptible-vms

Comment: @tsu1980 `Estafette GKE Node Pool Shifter` is certainly interesting but currently lacks support for Regional clusters (at least on GKE). It only supports Zonal clusters and incorrectly requests too many new nodes. For example, for a 3-zone cluster 3 times as many nodes will be created than desired. This currently makes it unusable for our needs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you can get exactly what you want with the Cluster Autoscaler but I'll hopefully give you a couple options and pointers to further explore.

- The Cluster Autoscaler has the notion of [Expanders](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/FAQ.md#what-are-expanders) which can help determine which node group to scale up when a scaling event happens. The `price` expander seems to be close to what you want, but based on the [description](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/proposals/pricing.md) of it, it doesn't look like it has support for preemptible VMs yet. You could explore that further, and possibly [submit a feature request](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/issues) to add support for preemptible node pools.
- When choosing a mixture of preemptible and non-preemptible nodes, whenever there is a stock out on GCP and preemptible nodes are not available, it's very likely that non-preemptible nodes will **also** not be available. In that case you may find yourself with a small number of non-preemptible nodes in the cluster and without the ability to create new ones.

  It may be a better idea to have a fixed minimum size of non-preemptible nodes, and auto-scale a preemptible node pool on top of that using the Cluster Autoscaler.